# The link between error bars representing the standard error of the mean and statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, standard-error

I have read the following on many websites:

> ***What can you conclude when standard error bars do not overlap?***
>
> When standard error (SE) bars do not overlap, you cannot be sure that
>   the difference between two means is statistically significant.
>
> ***What can you conclude when standard error bars do overlap?***
>
> When SE bars overlap,  you can be sure the difference between the two
>   means is not statistically significant (P>0.05).

I am wondering if this is true for both paired and independent samples t-tests, whether SE are computed on difference scores or for each condition separately.

Comment: The following link helped me a lot in answering questions about SE and t-test: http://fisbio.biof.ufrj.br/restrito/bioEstatistica/90_top_especiais/errorbars_stat_significance.htm

Comment: [Error bars in experimental biology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2064100/) covers this ground reasonably well.